# "Multimedia" or "media" for menu name

Tags: word-choice, nouns, hypernyms, internet

I'm developing a website on which photos and videos will be shared. But I couldn't decide on the main menu name to use under which there will be two subcategories *Photo Gallery* and *Videos*. Which one do you think makes more sense to visitors: *multimedia* or *media*? Once they see it, they should immediately realize this menu is all about photos, videos and things related to graphics.

Comment: I'm afraid that naming questions are normally off topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *multimedia* for the category and *photos* and *videos* for the subcategories. *Media* would refer to something else: newspapers, television, radio.